# findOne() returns "findById() no longer accepts a callback" error message, even if await is used

Tags: javascript, mongoose, passport-local

I know that the new mongoose versions removed the abillity to use callback functions with `Model.findOne` and that you have to use either promises or async functions which I think I did or am I wrong? Or is the problem that the `findOne` call is in a callback function by itself?

```
passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: "username",
        passwordField: "password"
    }, async (username,password,done) =>
    {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOne({username})
            if(!user)
            {
                return done(null,false,{message: "Username/Password incorrect"})
            }
            const isMatch = await user.isValidPassword(password);
            return isMatch ? done(null,user) : done(null,false,{message: "Username/Password incorrect"})
        } catch (error) {
            done(error);
        }
    })
)
```

For the sake of completeness here's the scheme and the validPassword function:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            lowercase: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
);


UserSchema.methods.isValidPassword = async function(password)
{
    try {
        return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password)
    } catch (error) {
        throw createHttpError.InternalServerError(error.message)
    }
}
```

I tried using promise and async functions and I tried to put everything from the try/catch block into its own function but `passport.use` needs a callback function and when I tried to pass the username to the new function I still got the same error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Also remember to make sure your title summarizes the problem: your code does not have `findById` in it, so your title doesn't make a lot of sense. Did you mean `findOne`?